# wxWidgets unpredictable Seg fault

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am writing a GUI that basically displays subsections of images to the user and asks for input. However, I am having a weird problem. About 40% of the time when I run the program, I will get a seg fault. The other 60% of the time it runs fine, with the exact same input.
Through mostly print statements I managed to narrow the seg fault down to this line:

```
subImage = image.GetSubImage(wxRect(wxPoint(0, iheight - 800), wxPoint(800, iheight)));
```

I've tried declaring the wxRect and wxPoint values outside of the GetSubImage call but that didn't work either.

This is a special case for when the subsection of the image to be displayed is off the edge of the image. This particular case just happens to be the first such subsection to be displayed. Image is the image that was loaded from the file of type wxImage. subImage is also a wxImage that I actually display.

The thing that confuses me the most about this is why it only happens some of the time when I use the exact same input.
Any help in even where to start working on is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

The whole code for my constructor is:

```
wxImagePanel::wxImagePanel(wxPanel* parent, wxString file, wxBitmapType format, int xloc, int yloc, int index, wxImage temp) : wxPanel(parent)
{
image = temp;
x = xloc;
y = yloc;
dIndex = index;
int iheight = image.GetHeight();
int iwidth = image.GetWidth();

if(x - 400 < 0)
{
    if(y - 400 < 0)
    {
        subImage = image.GetSubImage(wxRect(wxPoint(0,0), wxPoint(800,800)));
    }
    else if(y + 400 > iheight)
    {
        //here's the random seg fault
        subImage = image.GetSubImage(wxRect(wxPoint(0, iheight - 800), wxPoint(800, iheight)));
    }
    else
    {

        subImage = image.GetSubImage(wxRect(wxPoint(0,y-400), wxPoint(800, y+400)));
    }
}
else if (y - 400 < 0)
{
    if(x + 400 > iwidth)
    {
        subImage = image.GetSubImage(wxRect(wxPoint(iwidth - 800, 0), wxPoint(iwidth, 800)));
    }
    else
    {
        subImage = image.GetSubImage(wxRect(wxPoint(x-400,0),wxPoint(x+400,800)));
    }
}
else if((x + 400 < iwidth) && (y + 400 < iheight))
{
    subImage = image.GetSubImage(wxRect(wxPoint(x-400,y-400),wxPoint(x+400,y+400)));
}
else if(x + 400 > iwidth)
{
    if(y + 400 > iheight)
    {
        subImage = image.GetSubImage(wxRect(wxPoint(iwidth - 800, iheight - 800), wxPoint(iwidth, iheight)));
    }
    else
    {
        subImage = image.GetSubImage(wxRect(wxPoint(iwidth - 800, y-400), wxPoint(iwidth,y + 400)));
    }
}
else
{
    subImage = image.GetSubImage(wxRect(wxPoint(x - 400, iheight - 800),wxPoint(x + 400,iheight)));
}
w = -1;
h = -1;
```

Comment: If you can add some more code.. it'll be great

Comment: Try to narrow down using a debugger (GDB if possible). A possible reason is uninitialized pointer. Posting more code can help us provide accurate answers.

Comment: @vidit I added more code

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand the subimage spans outside the image?
I cannot tell you the solution to your particular problem, but I can give you two general advices when you work with wxWidgets:

- Ask your questions in the wx-users mailing list, they have excellent support and there is a big chance that a core developer will answer your question.
- The source code is your friend. The code of wxWidgets is really clean and well structured, easily readable. So you can try to build with a debug version of wxWidgets and run your app under a debugger to see what's going on. When your app crashes udner the debugger, you will see where in the wxWidgets code is the crash and you can see what's going on.